# HTML on GWT moves full template (and it shouldn't)

Tags: html, css, templates, gwt

I've been working on a page which has some HTML injected into the page, I had the same problem before, and it solved when I included my code into a table, but this time, I made a table and put my information in there.

The issue I'm having is, I have my template and 8 more links, 7 of them work properly (template stays on it's position), but 1 of them makes the template move 10px to the left.

I'm not sure if I explained my problem well, it's a visual issue, but it looks ugly everytime I click and all template moves.

When I click every link (1-7) template stays on black position (where it should be), but if I click on link8 template goes to the purple one.

http://i622.photobucket.com/albums/tt301/jesus1308/map.png

My template is on the center of the page, (950px width), that's why I can see what happens.

Last time my HTML was the problem, but now even when I did copy-paste and modified only text I can't fix this issue.

---

This is the code that is working properly:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Privacity</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><blockquote>BENEFITS AND MORE TEXT</blockquote></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><blockquote>
                    <img src="list.png" align="left" alt=""/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Element1 of list</b><br/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TEXT AND MORE TEXT<br/><br/>
                    <img src="list.png" align="left" alt=""/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Element2 of list</b><br/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;TEXT AND MORE TEXT<br/><br/>
                </blockquote></td>
                <td>
                    <blockquote><img src="image.png" align="right" alt=""/>
                    </blockquote>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the html that I have to correct:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Privacity</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table width="750px">
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><h3>PRIVACITY</h3></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>LOTS OF TEXT COME HERE<br/>
                REALLY A LOT OF TEXT IS IN HERE</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                 <td align="right">HERE COMES A BIT MORE TEXT</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here comes the CSS:

```
.fbwt-DeskBanner-img
{
    Z-INDEX: 100;
}

.fbwt-DeskPanel
{
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff;
    MARGIN: auto;
    TOP: 80px;
    WIDTH: 950px;
    Z-INDEX: 100;
}

.fbwt-DeskPanel-content
{
    BACKGROUND: #d9d9d9;
    WIDTH: 950px;
    FONT-SIZE: 10pt;
}
.fbwt-FormBuilder-label
{
    FONT-FAMILY: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    FONT-SIZE: 9pt;
}

.fbwt-Home
{
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d9d9d9;
    BOTTOM: 0;
    LEFT: 15px;
    MARGIN: auto;
    OVERFLOW: auto !important;
    POSITION: absolute !important;
    RIGHT: 0;
    TOP: 0;
}
```

Java file which injects HTML:

```
public final class PrivacityPage extends Page{

private final PublicTemplate template;

private final PpymeConstants constants;

private final PpymeCssBundle cssBundle;

private final PpymeHtmlBundle htmlBundle;

private final SimplePanel main = new SimplePanel();

@Inject
private PrivacityPage(PublicTemplate template, PpymeConstants constants,
         PpymeCssBundle cssBundle, PpymeHtmlBundle htmlBundle) {
this.template = template;
this.constants = constants;
this.cssBundle = cssBundle;
this.htmlBundle = htmlBundle;
}

@Override
public final Template getTemplate() {
return template;
}

@Override
public final void loadDynamicContent() {
}

@Override
public void loadStaticContent() {
main.setWidth("100%");
setWidget(main);
DOM.setStyleAttribute(main.getElement(), "backgroundColor","white");
DOM.setStyleAttribute(main.getElement(), "borderRadius","10px 0px 10px 10px");
HTML content = new HTML(htmlBundle.privacity().getText());
main.setWidget(content);
}
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid that without sharing that html and css, you aren't going to get a lot of help - its sort of like emailing a a drawing of yourself to the doctor and asking for a diagnosis and treatment...

Comment: @ColinAlworth sorry for not posting HTML before, I tried to post before but couldn't, maybe now with this someone could help me.

Comment: The CSS you have posted has nothing to do with the HTML you have posted - if used together, it will do nothing. Is there any other CSS that is present?

Comment: Nope, actually that's all code, but the Java file where I inject this, give me a sec, I post it